# VPN not connecting automatically in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

This could be a bug, a feature request or the fact that this feature was moved and I can't find the option in the new GUI.

In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, as in other versions, you can cause the VPN to connect automatically on bootup or login.

[image]

There is no such option that I can find in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  You can connect to wifi (or ethernet) automatically but there is no provision that I can see to also engage the VPN automatically (through the Network Manager).

Once I connect the VPN by moving the slider to "ON", the connection stays on even if I log off and another user logs on which is great.

[image]